# name this Romanesque surface

Tags: surfaces

I happened to notice that the surface
$$
x = \sin(u-v), y = \sin(v), z = \sin(-u)
$$
or equivalently (if I haven't blundered)
$$
x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 2 x^2 y^2 - 2 x^2 z^2 - 2 y^2 z^2 + 4 x^2 y^2 z^2 = 0
$$
resembles the [octahemioctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahemioctahedron) in the same way [Steiner's Roman surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_surface) resembles the [tetrahemihexahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahemihexahedron).

Has it a name?

Comment: The plane $z=0$ (for example) intersects your parametrically given surface at a segment of the line pair $(x=\pm y; z=0)$, but meets the algebraic surface along the whole of the line pair $(x=\pm y; z=0)$.

Comment: The parametric surface is of course bounded.  The real algebraic variety is, I think, the union of that and six lines (the ones @JohnBentin described and those obtained from them by permuting $x,y,z$)

Comment: Thank you. Can the algebraic equation be amended to avoid that flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathworld calls this the [sine surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineSurface.html).

[image: sine surface]

Comment: And that page gives an equation for it!